# How do I dump raw data from a TCP port in Windows using the netsh command?

Tags: windows, networking, tcp, netsh

I have an apparently simple issue which is proving very difficult to find an answer for.

The site has a highly-secured Windows Server 2019 installation and an appliance connected to it running on a certain TCP port.

I need a sample of the raw data coming out of that port, taken for a few minutes, dumped into a binary file. It needs to be as raw as possible (i.e. it needs to resemble what we would read from the TCP stream when we would connect to that same port from a local .NET application).

It is **highly** preferable to use only built-in Windows tools for this (i.e. `netsh`), but worst-case `windump` or `telnet` are also fine.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with netsh:

Run this command as admin:

```
netsh trace start capture=yes tracefile=c:\temp\trace.etl
```

then, stop the capture with `netsh trace stop` and grab the `.etl` file.

Download [etl2pcapng](https://github.com/microsoft/etl2pcapng) on your computer, and use it to convert the .etl file in the pcapng format: `etl2pcapng.exe in.etl out.pcapng`

Finally, open the pcapng file with Wireshark or similar.

Note that if the server runs at least Windows Server 2019 Update 2004, you can use [pktmon](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/networking-blog/introducing-packet-monitor/ba-p/1410594) too.